# Move UI Buttons in a VR application based on Google VR sdk in Unity

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, google-vr

It is a simple VR application to view 360 degree photos. I have UI buttons for next and previous photo. What I want is that when a person is viewing a photo at any angle around 360, and if he sees below he should get those UI buttons.

I have tried to rotate those UI button with the camera using `Quaternion.RotateTowards` , `Quaternion.Slerp`, `Quaternion.SlerpUnclamped` but the results are not like what we see in similar VR applications.

I am using GoogleVR sdk. Please Help.

In the screen shot the scene is in play mode. See the rotation of Camera. Originally it is at (0,0,0) but I am watching beneath so are the updated rotation. Yo can see the round blue buttons that is UI on canvas.

What I want is that when I look round these buttons should remain beneath. Or in other words whenever I look beneath, I should see these buttons. As in real I can move around but whenever I see beneath I would see my shoes.https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1Fvz.jpg
Second Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLKmp.jpg

Comment: Provide an example of what you want, preferably in the form of a screenshot.

Comment: Kindly see my answer where I have uploaded the figure and elaborated it.

Comment: SO is not a forum. Remove your answer and add it to the question by editing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a screen-space canvas in your scene. Change it to world-space (on the Canvas object, change Render Mode to World Space), then position it beneath the camera. It will appear below. If you move your camera around, you'll need to update the canvas to stay with the camera. This script will do it for you:

```
Transform cameraTransform; // find the camera transform in some way at startup, it depends on your scene setup

void Update() {
    transform.position = cameraTransform.position + Vector3.down * 5; // change 5 to whatever distance you want the canvas to sit from the camera
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(90 /* face-up */, 0, -cameraTransform.rotation.y /* rotate to match heading of camera */);
}
```

Comment: I tried it but still not working. Kindly see the second image I have uploaded. You can see that when moving around, the blue UI buttons are not straight. Do you mean that Canvas should be the child of the camera? I tried that as well but did not get the required output.

Thanks for answering...

Comment: Did you use the script I gave you? BTW, how's the user gonna point her head at the buttons if they keep rotating along with her head?